# How to replace "&A-Z" with the orinal text minus the &

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm looking for a way to replace "&" from a text string when it's followed by text. For example;

Input Text: "Ne&w && Edit Record"
Required Output: New & Edit Record"

The reason for "Ne&w" is that "&" then shows w as the shortcut key (underscored in the UI) and the reason for the "&&" is so that a single "&" is displayed in the text.

When using the input text as the value for the text propery on a command button the text displays as expected, but when I pass the text property to a message box it displays the input text in the message box dialog.

I don't want to use the Tag property to store the message I want in the message box as I use the tag property for another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all `&` signs not followed by a `&` sign. Match them like this:

```
&(?!&)
```

See it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/aW7oL8)

Comment: In your example this `Ne&w &&&& Edit Record` would become `New &&& Edit Record`, while OP is probably looking for `New && Edit Record`.

Comment: The match expression suggested by @mrhobo worked perfectly here is my final function
    Public Shared Function RegExReplace(input As String,    matchExpression As String) As String Dim output As String = Nothing ' Replace "Nothing" with RegEx when known! output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "&(?!&)", "") Return output End Function

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim input As String = "Ne&w && Edit Record"
Dim output As String = "New & Edit Record"
Dim p As String = Regex.Replace(input, "&(?<first>\w|&)", "${first}")
MessageBox.Show(output = p) 'shows True
```

In the above Regex expression I am capturing an ampersand followed by either a letter or another ampersand, and replacing that sequence with a symbol coming after the ampersand. `<first>` is a named group, it is used for Regex replacement.

See [Regex.Replace on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx).